# Using SPARQL "from" with both a graph and a graph group in Virtuoso 7.20.3217

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have a graph group `<group>` of *m* graphs `<group_1>`...`<group_m>` with *n* total triples. When I do a count together with a graph `<graph>` with *k* total triples outside of the graph group, I only get the number of triples *n* in the graph group:

```
select count(*)
from <group>
from <graph>
{?s ?p ?o}
```

Result: *n*

When I list the graphs in the graph group explicitly, however, I get the correct result:

```
select count(*)
from <group_1>
from <group_2>
...
from <group_m>
from <graph>
{?s ?p ?o}
```

Result: *n* + *k*

How can I obtain the correct result with the graph group and what is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You should use either two subqueries like this for example:

```
select ?n ?k (?n + ?k as ?totalCount) where {
  { select (count(*) as ?n) where {
      graph group: { ?s ?p ?o } }
  { select (count(*) as ?k) where {
      graph graph: { ?s ?p ?o } }
}
```

Or use a union:

```
select (count(?s1) as ?n)
       (count(?s2) as ?k)
       (?n + ?k as ?totalCount)
where {
  { graph group: { ?s1 ?p1 ?o1 } }
  union
  { graph graph: { ?s2 ?p2 ?o2 } }
}
```

Comment: There are syntax errors when I execute your first query and it returns 0 triples for the graph group when I fix them (parentheses in the sum, removing the ":", add missing braces).